# CEF3 browser displaying pages incorrectly

Tags: c++, winapi, chromium-embedded

I've been working to display a Chromium Embedded Framework browser window in my borderless win32 window. So far the window is created and the browser loads in, but two issues have presented.

1. Messages don't seem to be getting sent to my window callback (which of course causes window dragging to not function).
2. The browser is distorting the pages (almost like only some css is being loaded)

I'm presuming this is due to some glaring mistake I've made in implementing CEF3. What I have is cobbled together from the two example projects that come with a nightly build of CEF3. So the question is, does anyone see any clear mistakes I've made in implementing the browser?

Here's my Main.cpp

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include "include/cef_base.h"
#include "include/cef_app.h"
#include "ClientApp.h"
#include "ClientHandler.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "lib/libcef.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "lib/libcef_dll_wrapper.lib")

// Fix Conflicting Macros
#define GET_X_LPARAM(lp)    ((int)(short)LOWORD(lp))
#define GET_Y_LPARAM(lp)    ((int)(short)HIWORD(lp))

// Window Variables
HINSTANCE g_instance;
HWND g_hwnd;
LPCWSTR g_window_class = L"MyUI";
INT g_window_width = 670;
INT g_window_height = 540;
BOOL g_drag_window = false;
SHORT g_mouse_x, g_mouse_y, g_mouse_x_prev, g_mouse_y_prev;

// CEF Variables
CefRefPtr<ClientApp> g_app;
CefRefPtr<ClientHandler> g_client_handler;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            CefQuitMessageLoop();
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }

        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            // Set window attributes
            RECT rect;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
            CefWindowInfo info;
            info.SetAsChild(hWnd, rect);

            // Set browser settings
            CefBrowserSettings settings;

            //Create handler
            ::g_client_handler = new ClientHandler();

            // Create browser
            CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowserSync(info, ::g_client_handler.get(), 
                "http://wikipedia.com", settings, NULL);

            break;
        }

        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        {
            g_mouse_x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
            g_mouse_y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
            if (g_mouse_y < 41)
            {
                g_mouse_x_prev = g_mouse_x;
                g_mouse_y_prev = g_mouse_y;
                SetCapture(hWnd);
                g_drag_window = true;
            }
            MessageBox(NULL, L"FLDKSJA", L"", MB_OK);
            break;
        }

        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        {
            if (g_drag_window)
            {
                g_drag_window = false;
                ReleaseCapture();
            }
            break;
        }

        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        {
            if (g_drag_window && (wParam & MK_LBUTTON))
            {
                // code executed when the dialog window is moved around on the screen
                RECT win_rect;
                GetWindowRect(hWnd, &win_rect);
                int x_coord = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
                int y_coord = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
                MoveWindow(hWnd,
                    win_rect.left + x_coord - g_mouse_x_prev,
                    win_rect.top + y_coord - g_mouse_y_prev,
                    win_rect.right - win_rect.left,
                    win_rect.bottom - win_rect.top,
                    false
                    );
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        }

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

BOOL InitWindow()
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    // Register window class
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_DROPSHADOW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = ::g_instance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = ::g_window_class;
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        wchar_t msg[100];
        wsprintf(msg, L"Unable to register class!\nError: %i", GetLastError());
        MessageBox(NULL, msg, L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Create window
    ::g_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                        // Optional window styles.
        ::g_window_class,         // Window class
        L"",                      // Window text
        WS_POPUP,     // Window style

        // Position and size
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, ::g_window_width, ::g_window_height,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        ::g_instance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
        );

    if (!::g_hwnd)
    {
        wchar_t msg[100];
        wsprintf(msg, L"Unable to create window!\nError: %i", GetLastError());
        MessageBox(NULL, msg, L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return FALSE;
    }

    //Display window
    ShowWindow(::g_hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    UpdateWindow(::g_hwnd);

    return TRUE;
}

INT APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    ::g_instance = hInstance;

    // Provide CEF with command-line arguments.
    CefMainArgs main_args(hInstance);

    // CEF applications have multiple sub-processes (render, plugin, GPU, etc)
    // that share the same executable. This function checks the command-line and,
    // if this is a sub-process, executes the appropriate logic.
    int exit_code = CefExecuteProcess(main_args, NULL, NULL);
    if (exit_code >= 0) {
        // The sub-process has completed so return here.
        return exit_code;
    }

    // Specify CEF global settings here.
    CefSettings settings;
    settings.no_sandbox = true;
    settings.multi_threaded_message_loop = false;
    settings.pack_loading_disabled = true;

    // ClientApp implements application-level callbacks for the browser process.
    ::g_app = new ClientApp();

    // Initialize CEF.
    CefInitialize(main_args, settings, ::g_app.get(), NULL);

    // Create main window.
    if (!InitWindow())
    {
        CefShutdown();
        return 1;
    }

    // Process messages.
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

        CefDoMessageLoopWork();
    }

    // Shut down CEF.
    CefShutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

ClientApp.h

```
#pragma once
#include "include/cef_app.h"

class ClientApp : public CefApp,
                  public CefBrowserProcessHandler,
                  public CefRenderProcessHandler
{
public:
    ClientApp();
    ~ClientApp();

    // CefBase
    IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(ClientApp);

    // CefApp
    virtual CefRefPtr<CefBrowserProcessHandler> GetBrowserProcessHandler()
    {
        return this; 
    }

    virtual CefRefPtr<CefRenderProcessHandler> GetRenderProcessHandler()
    {
        return this;
    }

    //Context
    virtual void OnContextCreated(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
        CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
        CefRefPtr<CefV8Context> context);
};
```

ClientHandler.h

```
#pragma once
#include "include\cef_client.h"

class ClientHandler : public CefClient,
                      public CefLifeSpanHandler,
                      public CefLoadHandler
{
public:
    ClientHandler();
    ~ClientHandler();

    // CefClient
    virtual CefRefPtr<CefLifeSpanHandler> GetLifeSpanHandler()
    {
        return this;
    }
    virtual CefRefPtr<CefLoadHandler> GetLoadHandler()
    { 
        return this;
    }


    // CefBase
    IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(ClientHandler);
};
```

And this is how the browser is displaying Wikipedia.com:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the generic code for both single threaded and multi threaded.

```
if (!settings.multi_threaded_message_loop) {
  // Run the CEF message loop. Blocks until recieves a WM_QUIT message.
  CefRunMessageLoop();
} else {
  MSG msg;
  // Run the application message loop.
  while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
  if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
}
```

In other words try CefRunMessageLoop() alone.